# Run simple executable jar with boxfuse

Tags: java, maven, cloudcaptain

I want to convert an application that currently runs with docker to boxfuse.

After the maven build, I have these relevant files:

```
/target/my-app-shaded.jar
/config-dev.yml
```

The command to run the jar locally would be simply `jar -jar target/my-app-shaded.jar server config-dev.yml`

What I could figure out is that `boxfuse run target/my-app-shaded.jar` runs the jar file, but how do I add the config file and the command line arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a Dropwizard application. In that case you can simply place your configuration under `src/main/resources` and pass the arguments like this

`boxfuse run target/my-app-shaded.jar "-jvm.main.args=server config-dev.yml"`

When executing this at the root of your Maven or Gradle project and using the latest Boxfuse Client (you can simply update with `boxfuse -u`), you can also simplify this to:

`boxfuse run "-jvm.main.args=server config-dev.yml"`

As Boxfuse will auto-discover the payload.

Also if you name your config file `boxfuse.yml` you can simply this even further to:

`boxfuse run`

More info: https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/payloads/dropwizard#configuration

Comment: Actually it is but an older 0.6.5 which isn't supported by boxfuse. What would be the manual fat-jar way? (I'm eager to learn details). It might be that the old dropwizard version doesn't support reading from classpath but i might be wrong (never did that)

Comment: For manual fat-jars you have to package the config in the fat-jar and then you have 2 options: load the config programmatically from the classpath (this may help: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/409) or extract it manually on disk on startup and load it as a file.